# Execute a Script before shutting down

Tags: 16.04, scripts, shutdown, runlevel

I'm trying to execute a script before shutdown of a Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Here is the process I did:

1. Created a script in `/etc/init.d` ( `touch /etc/init.d/sample` )
2. Given execute permission ( `chmod a+x /etc/init.d/sample` )
3. Then created a soft links into `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d` 
        ( `ln -s /etc/init.d/sample /etc/rc0.d/K99sample /etc/rc6.d/K99sample` )
4. I checked it but it is not working.

I did the same process in Ubuntu 14.04,and it is working awesomely.

What could be the issue?

Comment: have a look at this question and its answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown                       
ubuntu 16.04 is using `systemd` for most of its `init` stuff.